# Uploading to cloud storage from remote location (https address)

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to upload a dataset(zip file, 200mb) to google cloud storage without saving it locally (ideally using command line interface). In other words, I want to use https address to upload a file from remote location.

I tried to use

1. gsutil, but looks like it only works with local files --
   [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil#upload_an_object_into_your_bucket)
2. Transfer service console -- I get UNKNOWN errors

> Errors UNKNOWN: (showing 1 of 1 failures) Object: http_list_0 Details:
>   Unknown error. UNKNOWN: (showing 1 of NaN failures) Object:
>   http_list_0 Details: Unknown error. UNKNOWN: (showing 1 of NaN
>   failures) Object: http_list_0 Details: Unknown error.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, after reading docs once again I realized that the errors are probably caused by the fact that I am providing URL of the file I want to upload instead of a url to a file with TsvHttpData (which supposed to contain MD5 hash along with links... which I guess means I wont be able to use Transfer Service for my purpose?)

Comment: I think you can use the same approach I described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47778015/download-public-data-to-google-storage