# Download public data to google storage

Tags: download, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to download public data directly from the link to my google storage bucket using **gsutil**. I can't any command to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl to get data from a link and pipe it to gsutil (which will stream it to Google Cloud Storage) like so:

`curl 'https://www.website.com/link-to-your-data' | gsutil cp - gs://your-bucket-name/your-object-name`

Comment: This will depend on my local computer's internet bandwidth.
I want to upload directly to the bucket without routing from my local computer.

Comment: You listed gsutil as a requirement in your question - unless you're copying objects within Google Cloud Storage, any data gsutil sees will necessarily go through your local computer.

To avoid this, you could use the Cloud Transfer service with a URL list that you provide, but you would need to calculate the MD5's of the objects you wanted to transfer.  See https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/create-url-list